# Using Table Valued Parameter as Stored Procedure Input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is it good to use table-valued parameter as stored procedure input? Can anyone tell me the scenarios which can use them to improve the query performance?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? Can you show us some example code?

Comment: When ever you need to pass array like data, tvp are very useful.

Comment: We have an online application which insert data to the table when user clicks save. instead of calling the SP for each button click, we thought to make a bulk insert to the table. We Thought to create a TVP in .net code and insert data into it temporarily, then moved to the table by calling sp once. is it a good approach?. I just need to know which approach is more feasible.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea - and it's a good idea any time you need to pass **multiple values** (e.g. a list of ID's to process etc.) instead of using e.g. comma-separated string (or XML) with the values and having to parse it in the stored procedure

Comment: If we don't have any multiple value parameters, which approach is good?

Comment: Performance has to do with what the procedure does, and how many times. I've yet to bump into a procedure that would "perform" better simply based on what kind of a parameter it got in. I suppose if you need to run your proc 50 times in a row for each separate parameter value in an array, then it would be better to pass a table type in to allow the whole set being run at once.  I've done a proc where you pass a table name and a table type containing a range of ID's for instance, where the proc would then find all references to and from said table with the provided primary key ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on role of procedure. For example, we got in our application creating reports with invoices which have specified statuses ( invoice read, invoice to accept etc. ). This functionality works for many clients, and many clients has his own list of statuses. To accomplish it, we call procedure with table-valued parameter containing list of required invoice statuses.